# transform child is out of bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Everything else is working correctly and the function is being called and proccesed however it pops an out of bounds error and I have no idea why, the gameObject that has the tag item has as first child(0) an empty gameObject that holds the different gameObjects I want to spawn, this child is not tagged and is SetActive(false) I have no idea why it is not working

The rest of the code works as intended I put it in here just as context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class PlayerControllerV01q : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Basico")]
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public PlayerInput input;


    [Header("Movement")]
    private float speed;
    public float speedMax, speedMin, accelerationSpeed;
    private float acceleration;

    private Vector3         dir;
    public float            gravity;
    public float            jumpForce;
    public float            speedRotation;
    public Transform        groundPoint;
    public bool             isGrounded;
    public LayerMask        maskGround;
    // public int totalJumps;
    //int currentJumps;
    public float            airTime;
    public float            bufferAirTime;
    public float            secondsInAir;


    [Header("Actions")]
    public float            killJump;
    public float            attackArea;
    public bool             holdingItem;
    public String[]         itemTags;
    public float            pickUpArea;
    public GameObject       detectedObject;
    public float            throwForce;
    public Transform        throwPlace;
    [Header("Button")]
    public GameObject       activableButton;
    public GameObject       DetectedButtonCandidate;
    public float            activableArea;
    //public bool             pressedButton;
    public String[]         buttonTags;


    public Animator anim;
    [Header("Deaths")]

    [Header("Surfaces")]
    public bool             isInwall;
    public Transform        facePoint;
    public LayerMask        maskWall;
    public Vector3          dirWall;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (input.actions["Grab"].WasPressedThisFrame())
        {
            Debug.Log("I am trying to grab");
            Collider[] allDetects = Physics.OverlapSphere(throwPlace.transform.position, pickUpArea);

            for (int i = 0; i < allDetects.Length; i++)
            {

                GameObject detectedObjectCandidate = allDetects[i].gameObject;

                // Check if the detected object's tag is in the itemTags array
                if (Array.Exists(itemTags, tag => tag == detectedObjectCandidate.tag))
                {
                    detectedObject = detectedObjectCandidate;
                    holdingItem = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        if (holdingItem == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("I am actually grabbing");
            detectedObject.transform.SetParent(transform);

            if (detectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
            {
                Rigidbody detectedObjectRB = detectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                if (input.actions["Throw"].WasPressedThisFrame())
                {
                    Debug.Log("I am trying to throw this");
                    detectedObject.transform.parent = null;
                    detectedObjectRB.AddForce(Vector3.forward * throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
                    holdingItem = false;
                }
            }
        }



        Vector2 move = input.actions["Move"].ReadValue<Vector2>();

        if(move.y != 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Move", true);
            anim.SetFloat("Speed", move.y);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("Move", false);
        }
        


        if(move.magnitude != 0)
        {

            acceleration = Mathf.MoveTowards(acceleration, 1.0f, Time.deltaTime * accelerationSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            
            acceleration = 0;
        }

        speed = Mathf.Lerp(speedMin, speedMax, acceleration);
        dir = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, move.y * speed));
        
        rb.velocity = dir;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * move.x * speedRotation * Time.deltaTime);

        isGrounded = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundPoint.position, 0.2f, maskGround).Length > 0;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Ground", true);
            airTime = 0;
            if (input.actions["Jump"].WasPressedThisFrame())
            {
                rb.velocity *= 0;
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
            Collider[] allDetects = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundPoint.transform.position, attackArea);
            for (int i = 0; i < allDetects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (allDetects[i].GetComponent<DestroyObject>() != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("I am jumping higher");
                    rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * killJump * 0.8f, ForceMode.Impulse);
                    airTime = 0;
                    allDetects[i].GetComponent<DestroyObject>().GetHits();
                }
            }
            airTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (input.actions["Jump"].IsPressed() && secondsInAir >= airTime && airTime >= bufferAirTime)
            {
                //Debug.Log("I am jumping higher");
                //playerRb.velocity *= 0; Esto aqui no func iona
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce * 0.8f, ForceMode.Force);

            }
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * gravity, ForceMode.Force);
        }

        isInwall = Physics.OverlapSphere(facePoint.position, 0.4f, maskWall).Length > 0;

        if (isInwall)  
        
        {
            if (input.actions["Climb"].IsPressed())
            {
                Debug.Log("Im trying to climb");
                dir = Vector3.zero;

                dirWall = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, move.y * speed, rb.velocity.y));
                rb.velocity = dirWall;
            }

                

        }

        if (input.actions["Grab"].WasPressedThisFrame())
        {         
            Collider[] allDetects = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, activableArea);

            for (int i = 0; i < allDetects.Length; i++)
            {
                allDetects = allDetects.Where(col => col.gameObject != gameObject).ToArray();
                // Check if the detected object's tag is in the itemTags array
                if (buttonTags.Contains(allDetects[i].tag))
                {
                    DetectedButtonCandidate = allDetects[i].gameObject;
                    activableButton = DetectedButtonCandidate;
                    pressedButton();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void pressedButton()
    {

        Transform activableButtonChildTransform = activableButton.transform.GetChild(0);

        if (activableButtonChildTransform != null)
        {
            GameObject activableButtonChild = activableButtonChildTransform.gameObject;
            activableButtonChild.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want it to get its first children and make it active.

```
UnityException: Transform child out of bounds
PlayerControllerV01q.pressedButton () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControllerV01.cs:218)
PlayerControllerV01q.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControllerV01.cs:209)
```

Comment: well one thing i assure you a billion times over is most people are not going to find out which is line 218..  but that first line assumes there is a child.. im going to suggest that something with a tag shouldnt have... and so desnt have the children you think it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are checking if a (non nullable) [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) is null. This will not give you the results you are looking for.
Aside from that if the GameObject does not have any children you would receive the Out of Bounds Error.

```
...
public void pressedButton()
{

   Transform activableButtonChildTransform = 
   activableButton.transform.GetChild(0);
   if (activableButtonChildTransform != null)...
   ...
}
```

I would recommend using the property transform.[ChildCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html) as a condition for the GetChild(0) function. Try something like this:

```
...
public void PressedButton()
{
   if (activableButton.transform.ChildCount > 0)
      activableButton.transform.GetChild(0).SetActive(true);
   else Debug.Warn($"{activableButton.name} does not have Child Objects");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if gameObject has child then execute code.

**Use Following Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class PlayerControllerV01q : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Basico")]
public Rigidbody rb;
public PlayerInput input;


[Header("Movement")]
private float speed;
public float speedMax, speedMin, accelerationSpeed;
private float acceleration;

private Vector3         dir;
public float            gravity;
public float            jumpForce;
public float            speedRotation;
public Transform        groundPoint;
public bool             isGrounded;
public LayerMask        maskGround;
// public int totalJumps;
//int currentJumps;
public float            airTime;
public float            bufferAirTime;
public float            secondsInAir;


[Header("Actions")]
public float            killJump;
public float            attackArea;
public bool             holdingItem;
public String[]         itemTags;
public float            pickUpArea;
public GameObject       detectedObject;
public float            throwForce;
public Transform        throwPlace;
[Header("Button")]
public GameObject       activableButton;
public GameObject       DetectedButtonCandidate;
public float            activableArea;
//public bool             pressedButton;
public String[]         buttonTags;


public Animator anim;
[Header("Deaths")]

[Header("Surfaces")]
public bool             isInwall;
public Transform        facePoint;
public LayerMask        maskWall;
public Vector3          dirWall;
void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if (input.actions["Grab"].WasPressedThisFrame())
    {
        Debug.Log("I am trying to grab");
        Collider[] allDetects = Physics.OverlapSphere(throwPlace.transform.position, pickUpArea);

        for (int i = 0; i < allDetects.Length; i++)
        {

            GameObject detectedObjectCandidate = allDetects[i].gameObject;

            // Check if the detected object's tag is in the itemTags array
            if (Array.Exists(itemTags, tag => tag == detectedObjectCandidate.tag))
            {
                detectedObject = detectedObjectCandidate;
                holdingItem = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    if (holdingItem == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("I am actually grabbing");
        detectedObject.transform.SetParent(transform);

        if (detectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
        {
            Rigidbody detectedObjectRB = detectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            if (input.actions["Throw"].WasPressedThisFrame())
            {
                Debug.Log("I am trying to throw this");
                detectedObject.transform.parent = null;
                detectedObjectRB.AddForce(Vector3.forward * throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
                holdingItem = false;
            }
        }
    }



    Vector2 move = input.actions["Move"].ReadValue<Vector2>();

    if(move.y != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("Move", true);
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", move.y);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("Move", false);
    }
    


    if(move.magnitude != 0)
    {

        acceleration = Mathf.MoveTowards(acceleration, 1.0f, Time.deltaTime * accelerationSpeed);
    }
    else
    {
        
        acceleration = 0;
    }

    speed = Mathf.Lerp(speedMin, speedMax, acceleration);
    dir = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, move.y * speed));
    
    rb.velocity = dir;
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * move.x * speedRotation * Time.deltaTime);

    isGrounded = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundPoint.position, 0.2f, maskGround).Length > 0;

    if (isGrounded)
    {
        anim.SetBool("Ground", true);
        airTime = 0;
        if (input.actions["Jump"].WasPressedThisFrame())
        {
            rb.velocity *= 0;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
        Collider[] allDetects = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundPoint.transform.position, attackArea);
        for (int i = 0; i < allDetects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allDetects[i].GetComponent<DestroyObject>() != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("I am jumping higher");
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * killJump * 0.8f, ForceMode.Impulse);
                airTime = 0;
                allDetects[i].GetComponent<DestroyObject>().GetHits();
            }
        }
        airTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (input.actions["Jump"].IsPressed() && secondsInAir >= airTime && airTime >= bufferAirTime)
        {
            //Debug.Log("I am jumping higher");
            //playerRb.velocity *= 0; Esto aqui no func iona
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce * 0.8f, ForceMode.Force);

        }
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * gravity, ForceMode.Force);
    }

    isInwall = Physics.OverlapSphere(facePoint.position, 0.4f, maskWall).Length > 0;

    if (isInwall)  
    
    {
        if (input.actions["Climb"].IsPressed())
        {
            Debug.Log("Im trying to climb");
            dir = Vector3.zero;

            dirWall = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, move.y * speed, rb.velocity.y));
            rb.velocity = dirWall;
        }

            

    }

    if (input.actions["Grab"].WasPressedThisFrame())
    {         
        Collider[] allDetects = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, activableArea);

        for (int i = 0; i < allDetects.Length; i++)
        {
            allDetects = allDetects.Where(col => col.gameObject != gameObject).ToArray();
            // Check if the detected object's tag is in the itemTags array
            if (buttonTags.Contains(allDetects[i].tag))
            {
                DetectedButtonCandidate = allDetects[i].gameObject;
                activableButton = DetectedButtonCandidate;
                pressedButton();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
public void pressedButton()
{
    if (activableButton.transform.childCount > 0)
    {
        activableButton.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

}
```